# How do I get Django to log why an sql transaction failed?

Tags: python, mysql, django, pootle

I am trying to debug a Pootle (pootle is build on django) installation which fails with a django transaction error whenever I try to add a template to an existing language. Using the python debugger I can see that it fails when pootle tries to save a model as well as all the queries that have been made in that session.

What I can't see is *what specifically causes the save to fail*. I figure pootle/django must have added some database database constraint, how do I figure out which one? MySql (the database being used) apparently can't log just failed transactions.

Comment: Did you set `DEBUG = True` in your config?

Comment: Yes, but that still only gives me the queries, not why they failed

Comment: try to do `logging`. to get error. (or) paste the code. ll try to help.

Comment: Would be happy to do that, but I don't know what settings I should use

Comment: Install django debug toolbar, you can easily check all of the queries that have been executed

Comment: @SebastianBurzyński, that is probably the best approach, if you turn the comment into an answer, I will accept that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install django debug toolbar, you can easily check all of the queries that have been executed